# replace some value in sql with Null and perform count function in sql server while performing group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

there is  LAT_LONG field which I want to count for each ID,   the LAT_LONG contain some string value as 'null/null' which I want to replace with NULL, and than perform the group by operation

```
 select ID, COUNT(LAT_LONG) as LAT_LONG_CAT from mytable group by ID
```

How to replace 'null/null' string with Null in LAT_LONG field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT ID,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN LAT_LONG <> 'null/null'
                  THEN LAT_LONG END) AS LAT_LONG_CNT
FROM mytable
GROUP BY ID;
```

The above `CASE` expression will treat a value of `null/null` as `NULL`, otherwise it counts the `LAT_LONG` field directly.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server you can simply use [`NULLIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function like so:

```
SELECT lat_long, NULLIF(lat_long, 'null/null') AS lat_long_parsed FROM mytable
```

[Example on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=36a89f1054b76f2003fe4e47e911f601)

So in the end your query would be:

```
SELECT ID
     , COUNT(NULLIF(lat_long, 'null/null')) AS LAT_LONG_CAT
  FROM mytable
 GROUP BY id
```